# How to hide or show dynamically column of table created using datatables in javascript with javascript source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Do you know how to dynamically/later hide or show   column when datatable's source is javascript?

this method works for tables created with   html source but not with method created with javascript source?

```
 var table = $('#example').dataTable({
  "data": source,
  "columns": columns,
  "columnDefs": [
  {
    "targets": [ 0 ],
    "visible": false, // no worries for hiding column at start 
  });
    var col = table.column("1").visible(false); //error if source is javascript
```

Comment: my second  ? is an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out we can do like that:

```
 table.fnSetColumnVis(3, false);
```

It works when table is create with method `datatable` (old version)

in spite of `column()` wroks when table is created with method `Datatable`  (new version)

Comment: It does not work because you initialize dataTables the "old" way, with `dataTable()`. `column()` should be used when using the new dataTables 1.0.x API, eg `DataTable()`. It is perfectly well to accept your own answer, perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Comment: of thank you very much !!! you solved the mystery! I was becoming crazy! Your solution is better! you should write it as answere.